# Enthusiast badge iPhone app

Tags: support, badges, ios-app

I noticed my enthusiast badge is down to 1 day, after only having been active yesterday via the iPhone app "Stackviewer". Is logging in via this app not counted?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158121/logins-through-phone-app-dont-count-towards-enthusiast-fanatic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link provided in the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295183/enthusiast-badge-iphone-app#comment197811_295183) from [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) you'll find [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158122/158100) from [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters):

> Accessing your Stack Exchange data through the API does not count towards your fanatic and enthusiast badge progress.
>
> <s>External applications such as the iPhone app use the API, not direct access to the site></s> . If you use the mobile web interface instead, you are seen to use the site actively and such access is counted towards the badges.

From the MSE post [Last seen not updating when using Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/158100) from [Steven V](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/254973/steven-v) we learn from one of the developers:

> We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen" and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.

So to have a *visit* counted you'll need to use the site form either the full or mobile website view. Do notice that simply loading the site is not enough. You have to *use* it. What exactly counts as *use* is not known but only viewing the front page probably won't count.

Comment: The official mobile apps **do** count towards visits. [Meta Stack Exchange source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/215013).