# Enthusiast/Fanatic - phone, web app, android app: What counts?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, badge-progress

I found two questions, here and on MSE, relating to this:

- [Logins through phone app don't count towards enthusiast/fanatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158121/logins-through-phone-app-dont-count-towards-enthusiast-fanatic)
- [Enthusiast badge iPhone app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295183/enthusiast-badge-iphone-app)

But those two questions are from around 10 years ago.

Has anything changed: I'm currently using [Stack for Stack Overflow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.tylerbwong.stack&hl=en&gl=US) and my question is, does this count towards my Enthusiast and Fanatic badges?

Or if I access Stack Overflow on a mobile browser, does this count?

I started using Stack Overflow 8 years ago and I still don't have these badges so I want to earn them.

Comment: All the official apps have been abandoned, so all bets are probably off the table there

Comment: Who the heck is Tyler Wong?  That's not an official app, so they're *probably* using the API, and that *likely* doesn't count for those badges.

Comment: @rene You beat me to it. OP should be careful with that :-D

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine yeah, I was close to the "nuke user" button. Luckily no diamond here ;)

Comment: There are a lot of scammers taking advantage of the desperate need for a (dedicated) app after [it was abandoned](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678). For example, as a way to steal [credentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential#Information_technology). Fortunately, very few of them can spell properly, like "Stack Overflow" (very easy detection). There was [a meta question about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413342/is-this-app-a-legitimate-stack-overflow-app#comment881551_413342) in 2021.

Comment: And on Über meta: *[Malicious app that misuses Stack Overflow trademarks is up on the Google Play Store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370587/malicious-app-that-misuses-stack-overflow-trademarks-is-up-on-the-google-play-st)*. [From it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370587/malicious-app-that-misuses-stack-overflow-trademarks-is-up-on-the-google-play-st#comment1236894_370587): *"It's fairly obvious this is malware stealing credentials."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the site.  The site works really well in a mobile browser, so there's really no *need* for an app.

You have to "do something that isn't just hitting the main site" though; what this is, I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Come on, be my mate, what "else" beside mobile browser  :)

Comment: @AnelHodžić:  It's either a browser you launch from your main laptop or tower PC, a browser you launch from your tablet, or a browser you launch from your phone.  The stie works just fine with any of those.